# Purpose of return expression in c

Tags: c, function, return-type

```
#include<stdio.h>

long int multiplyNumbers(int n);

int main() 
{
    int n;

    printf("Enter a positive integer: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Factorial of %d = %ld", n, multiplyNumbers(n));

    return 0;
}

long int multiplyNumbers(int n)
{
    if (n>=1)
        return n*multiplyNumbers(n-1);
    else
        return 1;
}
```

What is the purpose of `return n*multiplyNumbers(n-1);` in the above program? what does it exactly do?

Comment: You should do some research about *recursion*

Comment: It returns the result of `n` multiplied with whatever the call `multiplyNumbers(n-1)` returns.

Comment: Pointless: `if (n>=1)` should be `if (n>1)`... This is going further than it needs to... Also, there is no need for the `else` in the function.

Comment: This is just a recursive factorial program.  It is often used to teach people about recursion, but I consider it a poor example since factorial is an iterative problem that doesn't require recursion.  So instead of using and discarding each multiplier, it instead saves them all on the stack until it reaches the bottom.  Tell your instructor it's an artificial example, and that you'd like to see an example that actually benefits from recursion.

Answer (score 2):

Okay so the code `n * multiplyNumbers(n-1)` is a *recursive call*, remember how a factorial of a number is n! = n*(n-1)* (n-2) * ... *(n-(n-1)), the `n * multiplyNumbers(n-1)` is following this definition of the factorial.

I recommend reading
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial
To better understand why we are using this recursive code.

Comment: n! = n*(n-1)* (n-2) * ... *(n-(n-1)) :)

Comment: Maybe we should leave it as "an exercise for the reader" to simplify `n - (n - 1)`?